# jQuery UI issue with jQueryEasy plugin

Tags: joomla-2.5, plugin, jquery, javascript

Hello I have an old `Joomla 2.5` site. I use the `jQueryEasy` for optimization and if I dont I get some random mootools error.

My issue is : I want to use the `draggable()` method of `jQuery UI`.
It seems that the `jQueryEasy` doesnt load the correct `jQuery UI` ( the one with the other libraries like draggable ).

What I tried:

**Inside a component's view I tried to load the cdns from `jQuery` and `jQuery UI`.**

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>
<div id="test">
   TEST TEST TEST
</div>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#test").draggable();
});
</script>
```

No errors , just not working.

**Load the same version of `jQuery + UI` from the `jQueryEasy plugin`.**

Same story. No errors , and didnt work.

**Created a new file in joomla root folder ( wanted to test a file outside of Joomla Environment )**

This worked perfectly. So I reached to the conclusion that the issue here is the jQueryEasy plugin.

**Stopped the plugin and tested the 1st step**

Worked again.

I cant unpublish the plugin, so is there any other way to load the correct jQuery UI and get my hands on `draggable()` method ?

Comment: not an answer, but you might give a shot to toomanyfiles, another plugin that enabled jQuery, it has a thorough configuration to choose the cdn / local versions of libraries. It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

`jQueryEasy` has a feature to ignore some scripts for getting stripped.

[image]

I removed the initialise of `jQuery UI`, I loaded it manually from template and excluded from plugin and everything worked like a charm

Comment: So you're going to load jQuery UI on every single page even though you may not need it? Not the best idea...it's a big library

Comment: @Lodder With the "template" I meant the view I need it. No Need to add it on main template